# Issues with using Liquibase on RedShift database

Tags: amazon-redshift, devops, maven-plugin, pipeline, liquibase

I have been trying to use this(https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-redshift/releases) plugin for my Redshift database but haven't been able to get it to work. I am primarily facing two issues.

1. Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "TAG". I got around this issue by creating the databasechangelog table manually.
2. Getting an error while inserting the record into the databasechangelog table, due to now() function being used by LB in the insert query.

I see that both the issues have been marked as fixed(https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-redshift/issues/9) ,however, i am still facing these issues. I cannot make any change manually in the jar files due to the nature of my project. Hence, would appreciate if somebody could provide any insights into this. I am also using `dbms="redshift"` in my **changelog.xml** file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Changelog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="devsh0" id="9.9.9.9" logicalFilePath="LOGICALPATH" runOnChange ="true" >
         <sqlFile 
            path="src/main/dbo/app-code.SQL"
            dbms="RedshiftDatabase"
            stripComments="true"
        />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

My changeset `(app-code.sql)` present at `src/main/dbo/`

```
create table Test_Table
(
  col1   VARCHAR(3) not null,
  col2   VARCHAR(20) not null,
  col3   VARCHAR(50) not null
)
```

**POM.XML**

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>local_redshift</groupId>
  <artifactId>local_redshift</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>redshift</id>
      <url>https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-maven-repository/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
       <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.43.1067</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-redshift</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>  -->
</dependencies>
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                   <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase.redshift.properties</propertyFile>
                   <changeLogFile>src/main/changelog/changelog-1.0.0.0.1.xml</changeLogFile>
                  <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>```
````

Comment: The dbms isn't set correctly otherwise it would GETDATE() - Can you share your changelog and changeset?

Comment: @sudo i have added the changelog and changeset. I have tried running it with dbms="RedshiftDatabase" and dbms="redshift" and dbms="redshiftdatabase", but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

In your **changelog.xml**  it is `dbms="RedshiftDatabase"` - it should be `dbms="redshift"`:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="devsh0" id="9.9.9.9" logicalFilePath="LOGICALPATH" runOnChange ="true" >
         <sqlFile 
            path="src/main/dbo/app-code.SQL"
            dbms="redshift"
            stripComments="true"
        />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Since it is wrongly specified the [RedshiftDatabase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-redshift/blob/main/src/main/java/liquibase/ext/redshift/database/RedshiftDatabase.java) won't be used.

Comment: As i mentioned in my description and also in my comment above, i tried the changelog.xml with dbms="redshift" too, but it hasn't worked. Is there anything else you think i am missing?